# how can I show concatenated string into autocomplete textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autocompletebox

I am trying to show concatenated string into autocomplete textbox
when user start typing it will search by last name. query will look into database for full name contains ... and in autosuggestion it will show full name, company

.
if I just search by last_name
and put last_name

```
MyCollection.Add(reader("last_name").ToString())
```

It shows result
however following code shows nothing

here is my code

can anyone please suggest me how to resolve this ?

```
Dim strauto As String

       Dim name As String
       name = Trim(txtCompanyKeyContacts.Text)
       If name = &quot;&quot; Then Exit Sub
       Dim cnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(&quot;dbcon&quot;).ConnectionString
       Dim con As New SqlConnection(cnString)

       Using con
           strauto = &quot;SELECT (FULL_NAME + ',' + Company + ',' + Status) as contact  FROM name where FULL_NAME like '%&quot; &amp; Replace(name, &quot;'&quot;, &quot;''&quot;) &amp; &quot;%' &quot;
           'SELECT last_name,FULL_NAME + ',' + Company + ',' + Status as contact FROM name&quot;
           con.Open()
           Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strauto, con)

           Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
           Dim MyCollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()

           If reader.HasRows = True Then
               While reader.Read()


                   ' MyCollection.Add(reader(&quot;FULL_NAME + ',' + Company + ',' + Status&quot;).ToString())
                   MyCollection.Add(reader(&quot;contact&quot;).ToString())
               End While
           End If



           txtCompanyKeyContacts.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyCollection
           con.Close()
       End Using
```

Comment: The standard autocomplete functionality requires that the text in the control itself actually match the start of the items from the autocomplete list.  If you want something else then you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: what do you mean by `contact ` in  `MyCollection.Add(reader(&quot;contact&quot;).ToString())`

Comment: Ops that quot has come randomly.. actual code is MyCollection.Add(reader("contact").ToString())

Comment: jmcilhinney- Problem is it shows some records not all.. but when I run same query in the sql svr it shows intended result

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion is a different direction...

I'd use a ComboBox instead to allow humans to see the list of suggestions. This will loosen things up a bit and result in more likely success IMO

```
    Dim sName As String = "elizibeth"
    Dim SQL As String = <x>
    SELECT [ContactName] + ' - ' + [CompanyName] Name
      FROM [northwind].[dbo].[Contacts] 
      WHERE soundex(ContactName) = soundex('<%= sName %>')
    </x>.Value
    Dim dt As DataTable = Gen.GetDataTable(SQL, sConnectNorthwind) ' my libray for a read-only datatable
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

Comment: very close... but When I used this I cant type more than a word in the combobox

Comment: Autocomplete is not perfect. Best when used with simple things like single words or codes. In some cases I monitor TextChanged and wait for 3 or 4 characters before presenting the user with a list of choices. This narrows a list considerably.